# Cache ODBC characters

Tags: php, crystal-reports, odbc, intersystems-cache

Ok our database is Intersystems Cache, I'm trying to get the values from this one table via php. I managed to get the values but some values are incomplete and have symbols at the end.

This are the characters.. php99¥7“\ß¦

Then I tried to get the values via crystal reports.. no symbols but still the long values are incomplete, I viewed the field type and it says String[30], so I thought it's limited to 30 characters. But when viewed in a vb application it shows more than 30 characters.

Example:

```
php = "The quick brown fox jumps overphp99¥7“\ß¦"
crystal reports = "The quick brown fox jumps over"
VB application = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

I don't have the source of the VB so I can't really see what sql its running.

Anyone can help meh...?

Comment: You can check the sql in crystal using the option `Database ---> Show SQL Query`..

Comment: yep already tried it but still the same, actually it's also incomplete in crystal,

Comment: I am sorry I don't have expertise in Crystal as a part of Vb

Comment: You have to check MAXLEN parameter for this property

Answer (score 1):

When working directly with globals in caché the constraints of length of columns of a table are not verified. 
This way it is possible to put info longer than the max length of a column into a row.

On the other hand ODBC and probably also crystal reports (I think they use odbc in the background) base their column length on the definition of the table.

The easy solution in this case is rising the length of the column in question. This will make crystal reports and php both return the correct value. The question is if that solves your problem. Perhaps you want the max length of the column to be 30 characters. In that case a hard check needs to be built into the VB application directly accessing the globals.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this bug too. Problem is caused by PDO_ODBC unicode conversions and I fixed it with patching PHP sources.

File: ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c
Replace line (#631 in my installation)

`S->cols[colno].datalen+1, &S->cols[colno].fetched_len);`

with

`S->cols[colno].datalen*2+1, &S->cols[colno].fetched_len);`

I know that this fix is not ideal, but it works good in my case.